# VirtualBox 4.3.xx on OSX 10.12.2 Fails to install

Tags: macos, install, virtualbox

I've tried googling this issue for awhile now and have been unable to find a solution.  I, for a specific reason, need to install an older version of virtual box.  However, every time I try I get this error:  Also I looked at this answer [VirtualBox 4.3.26 on OSX 10.10.2 Fails to install](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177868/virtualbox-4-3-26-on-osx-10-10-2-fails-to-install)

Any and all help is appreciated!

```
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: @(#)PROGRAM:Install  PROJECT:Install-1000
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: @(#)PROGRAM:Installer  PROJECT:Installer-909
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Hardware: MacBookPro11,5 @ 2.80 GHz (x 8), 16384 MB RAM
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Running OS Build: Mac OS X 10.12.2 (16C67)
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Env: __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Env: TMPDIR=/var/folders/p5/gw7jq5kj18x4zr47rpq_9qz80000gn/T/
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Env: HOME=/Users/RonkarrollsMBP
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Env: SHELL=/bin/bash
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Env: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ODeYSHVXQE/Listeners
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Env: Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zcdkengp6N/Render
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Env: LOGNAME=RonkarrollsMBP
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Env: XPC_SERVICE_NAME=com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x1000000d.Installer
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Env: COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Env: USER=RonkarrollsMBP
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Env: XPC_FLAGS=0x0
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Oracle VM VirtualBox 4.3.28 Installation Log
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Opened from: /Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg
Jan 21 04:27:44 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Product archive /Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg trustLevel=202
Jan 21 04:27:49 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: JS: Hardware architecture detected: x86_64
Jan 21 04:27:49 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: JS: OS version detected: 10.12.2
Jan 21 04:27:49 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: JS: system.run /bin/sh .. returned: 1 result=true
Jan 21 04:27:49 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: JS: result:true
Jan 21 04:27:54 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: InstallerStatusNotifications plugin loaded
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Administrator authorization granted.
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: ================================================================================
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: User picked Standard Install
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Choices selected for installation:
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]:     Install: "Oracle VM VirtualBox"
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]:     Install: "Oracle VM VirtualBox Kernel Extensions"
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]:         VirtualBox.pkg#VBoxKEXTs.pkg : org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts : 4.3.28
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]:     Install: "Oracle VM VirtualBox"
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]:         VirtualBox.pkg#VirtualBox.pkg : org.virtualbox.pkg.virtualbox : 4.3.28
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]:     Install: "Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Utilities"
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]:         VirtualBox.pkg#VirtualBoxCLI.pkg : org.virtualbox.pkg.virtualboxcli : 4.3.28
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: ================================================================================
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: It took 0.00 seconds to summarize the package selections.
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: location = file://localhost
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VBoxKEXTs.pkg
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VirtualBox.pkg
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VirtualBoxCLI.pkg
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Set authorization level to root for session
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Will use PK session
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Using authorization level of root for IFPKInstallElement
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Starting installation:
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Configuring volume "Macintosh HD"
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Preparing disk for local booted install.
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Free space on "Macintosh HD": 114.04 GB (114043404288 bytes).
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Create temporary directory "/var/folders/p5/gw7jq5kj18x4zr47rpq_9qz80000gn/T//Install.886cpTfjV"
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: IFPKInstallElement (3 packages)
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Adding client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=886, uid=501 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer)
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: PackageKit: Enqueuing install with framework-specified quality of service (utility)
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: request=PKInstallRequest <3 packages, destination=/>
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: packages=(
        "PKLeopardPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VBoxKEXTs.pkg>",
        "PKLeopardPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VirtualBox.pkg>",
        "PKLeopardPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VirtualBoxCLI.pkg>"
    )
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Session UUID file exists - will not overwrite /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/8FCFC381-B776-4ABE-8043-8689F3B18BCC.activeSandbox
Jan 21 04:27:58 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VBoxKEXTs.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/8FCFC381-B776-4ABE-8043-8689F3B18BCC.activeSandbox/Root/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox, uid=0)
Jan 21 04:27:59 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VirtualBox.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/8FCFC381-B776-4ABE-8043-8689F3B18BCC.activeSandbox/Root/Applications, uid=0)
Jan 21 04:27:59 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VirtualBoxCLI.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/8FCFC381-B776-4ABE-8043-8689F3B18BCC.activeSandbox/Root/usr/bin, uid=0)
Jan 21 04:27:59 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: prevent user idle system sleep
Jan 21 04:27:59 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: suspending backupd
Jan 21 04:27:59 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Executing script "./preflight" in /private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.d9kctO/Scripts/org.virtualbox.pkg.virtualbox.W11QH8
Jan 21 04:27:59 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Using trashcan path /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/PKInstallSandboxTrash/8FCFC381-B776-4ABE-8043-8689F3B18BCC.sandboxTrash for sandbox /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/8FCFC381-B776-4ABE-8043-8689F3B18BCC.activeSandbox
Jan 21 04:27:59 Ronalds-MBP install_monitor[902]: Temporarily excluding: /Applications, /Library, /System, /bin, /private, /sbin, /usr
Jan 21 04:27:59 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Shoving /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/8FCFC381-B776-4ABE-8043-8689F3B18BCC.activeSandbox/Root (3 items) to /
Jan 21 04:28:00 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Executing script "./postflight" in /private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.d9kctO/Scripts/org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts.JqHrLo
Jan 21 04:28:00 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: ./postflight: /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxDrv.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) not loadable (reason unspecified); check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
Jan 21 04:28:00 Ronalds-MBP install_monitor[902]: Re-included: /Applications, /Library, /System, /bin, /private, /sbin, /usr
Jan 21 04:28:00 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: releasing backupd
Jan 21 04:28:00 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: allow user idle system sleep
Jan 21 04:28:00 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “VirtualBox.pkg”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=./postflight, NSURL=file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VBoxKEXTs.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “VirtualBox.pkg”.} {
        NSFilePath = "./postflight";
        NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cVirtualBox.pkg\U201d.";
        NSURL = "file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VBoxKEXTs.pkg";
        PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts";
    }
Jan 21 04:28:00 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Running idle tasks
Jan 21 04:28:00 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “VirtualBox.pkg”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=./postflight, NSURL=file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VBoxKEXTs.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “VirtualBox.pkg”.}
Jan 21 04:28:00 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Removing client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=886, uid=501 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer)
Jan 21 04:28:00 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Done with sandbox removals
Jan 21 04:28:01 Ronalds-MBP installd[337]: PackageKit: Sandbox /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/B2359A07-695B-445D-98BF-83676FE71755.sandbox: relevance 189
Jan 21 04:28:01 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
Jan 21 04:28:01 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: IFDInstallController 2001E0 state = 8
Jan 21 04:28:01 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
Jan 21 04:28:01 Ronalds-MBP Installer[886]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15832) in VirtualBox including the new 5.1 release.

One of the users posts that it could be a problem with VM Fusion:

> In my experience I get this exact error if I have VMware Fusion
>   installed. If I remove VMware Fusion (using AppCleaner) then I am able
>   to successfully install VirtualBox.

My suggestion is to either downgrade to El Capitan to use the VirtualBox that you need or to expand on your question as to why VirtualBox 4.3 is so critical - perhaps there is a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I need an older version of it to work with my current version of vagrant which I need to run some old servers :)  Ideally I would update everything but I was trying to avoid that for now.